# How can I define a function in TS that accepts argument which is part of a type union?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What I am trying to achieve is a TS definition that would tie value and a renderer function so by one of types defined in a typ union:

```js
interface MyObject {
  select: SelectData<string | number>
}

interface SelectData<T extends string | number> {
  values: T[]
  renderer: (values: T[]) => string
}

const obj: MyObject = {
  select: {
    values: [1, 2],
    renderer: (values: number[]) => 'sth'
  }
}

const obj: MyObject2 = {
  select: {
    values: ['one', 'two'],
    renderer: (values: string[]) => 'sth'
  }
}
```

TS returns error because number is not assignable to string, which makes sense. How can I change the TS definitions so that

1. for values of one type renderer would accept array of values of this type only
2. there would be several types that are acceptable, defined ideally in a type union
   ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understood the second point, but does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIEEBOBzBKAXigWB2QDs8oAfKSgVwFtUIcBuAKFEigGUImAMbAAIgENgEgDwAVYrEQoM2fAgB8ihRAAewCJQAmhOVyhQA-FADe5iw4BuE9IwgIAXFDkBtALrcDg44hkbs7F4AFM6u7l6+fgCUxFpkFNSBDgC+9l6UEI7s3FxUBjgAZhLC0ACyIADyqABWEKK29ghCrcBegiLiUrJpVDT0TKzsGtw5XMJwlGRQcM1edY0tbSR2Fp39XttOLm6eUD4AjAA0UABMfhf2FiHG4ThRMcd5LGw4-slEWgByMgACwB9wsWXuWW4QA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: "Move" the union bar outside: https://tsplay.dev/WGGAMW